# BB10 Core Native SDK: Programmatically adjust screen brightness?

Tags: c++, c, blackberry-10

Is it possible? If so please provide a working example.

I have come across [this function](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/bb10/screen_libref/topic/screen_get_window_property_iv.html) which can use the [SCREEN_PROPERTY_BRIGHTNESS](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/core/com.qnx.doc.screen.lib_ref/topic/screen_8h_1screen_property_types.html) to apparently change a windows brightness. However, I have had no success using this as there are no noticeable differences. In the comments below, see two other people who have had a similar issue (posted on the BlackBerry Support Forums). According to one user, the SCREEN_PROPERTY_BRIGHTNESS property does not work. Can anyone verify that or provide an alternative solution?

Comment: [bb-forums1](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-World-Development/Screen-brightness-How-to-drive-to-black/td-p/2337703) and [bb-forums2](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Native-Development/Screen-brightness-control/td-p/1919421) for similar issues

Comment: Did you test in the emulator or on a real device?

Comment: Real device, Blackberry Z10

Answer (score 0):

Your first link is to a page that does not exist. On the page from the second link there are to things. The property you want is probably SCREEN_PROPERTY_INTENSITY, but the documentation goes on to say

> Full read/write access to Screen API object properties is product
>   dependent.